# Friends, share your experience of how you found your full time sound design job, please

Tags: design, sound, format

I have just finished my BA in Music and I have been working on different sound design projects throughout studying. Now what I want is instead of proactively searching for gigs to present my sound works and to land on full time position. My believe is that working for a company or institution that can have Sound Designers on payroll will allow me to invest all of my time on things that I was learning and implementing for 4 years. Please share your experience how you have managed to achieve that sort of thing!

Comment: There's no money in music dude - everyone's got PCs and making bedroom music. The market is flooded with people giving away stuff. Sorry.

Comment: @dmitry - how will you select the right answer to this "question"? Please edit the topic to form an answerable question